# What does a function inside brackets and a minus sign mean?

Tags: optimization, notation, constraints, constraint-programming

I am working in constraint optimization. And I've just come across this notation.

I'm not sure what this means.

[image]

The set I is the set of inequality constraints. I'm not sure what the function in brackets means

Comment: Any more context you can give would be helpful. I don't know about the specific field of constraint optimisation, but that kind of notation in other areas is usually defined ad-hoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that $[y]^- = \min(y,0)$.

This notation is mentioned in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_and_negative_parts), but with a slight difference:  $[y]^- = -\min(y,0)$.

The important point is the minus sign as a superscript. The brackets are just like parentheses.

Comment: Other interpretations are possible, namely $\min(\lfloor y\rfloor ,0 )$ and $\min(\text{round}(y),0)$, where $\text{round}$ denotes the closest integer.

Comment: Thanks guys! This is helpful.